# Form inside Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, forms, html-table

I am using Javascript to show a sort of menu box with clickable links but I changed my mind and want to use links as forms now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $('.mouseon-examples div').data('powertipjq', $( [
    '<table class="tabulkajazyku"><form id="myformen" action="member" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="jazyk" value="en"><tr><td><a class="odkaz_cerveny odkaz_cerveny_block" href="#" id="mylinken"><img src="/images/flag_en.jpg" class="vlajky"><div class="posun5">EN</div></a></td></tr></form><form id="myformes" action="member" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="jazyk" value="es"><tr><td><a class="odkaz_cerveny odkaz_cerveny_block" href="#" id="mylinkes"><img src="/images/flag_es.jpg" class="vlajky"><div class="posun5">ES</div></a>&nbsp;</td></tr></form></table>'
    ].join('\n')));
$('.mouseon-examples div').powerTip({
    placement: 's',
    mouseOnToPopup: true
}); 
    </script>
```

In order to start form working I need this code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('mylinken').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('myformen').submit();
    return false;
}; 
document.getElementById('mylinkes').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('myformes').submit();
    return false;
};
```

};

It does not seem to be working. Instead of redirecting me to site called **member** thanks to **action="member"** and sending the form, it does just **href="#"** which stays at the same page and does nothing.

Honestly, I don't need the form to be a clickable link but a simple text does not work. I just need each row (tr) from the table to behave as a form.

I am a total beginner to Javascript following the rule of thumb.

I used the Table part on a different page (not in any Javascript code and everything is working fine).

Could you please help me where the error might be?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onload, use document.ready and instead of onclick use the jquery click handler and call e.preventDefault();

https://api.jquery.com/click/

Edit:
(sorry, I wrote the above on a mobile and it was too difficult to write code, here is the code for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mylinken, #mylinkes').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#myformen').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Edited to this: <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('mylinken').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('myformen').submit();
        return false;
    }); 
    document.getElementById('mylinkes').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('myformes').submit();
        return false;
    });    
});
</script> Still not working properly. Probably have a mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0):

The click events won't be bound to the elements, because the elements doesn't exist when the code runs. The elements won't exist until the user causes the tooltip to display.

You can use delegated events in jQuery to bind the event to an existing parent element and look for events that bubble up to it. That way the events can be bound for elements that doesn't exist yet:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#mylinken', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myformen').submit();
  }); 
  $(document).on('click', '#mylinkes', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myformes').submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great, now it redirects me to member site so the form partly works. However, when I want to echo some info on member site, it does not show up. `if ($_POST['jazyk'] == 'en' OR $_POST['jazyk'] == 'es'){
 echo ' OK '; }`

Comment: Not very elegant, but I added `<form id="myformen2" action="member" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="jazyk" value="en"></form><form id="myformes2" action="member" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="jazyk" value="es"></form>` outside the javascript and it works! It is a hidden form so nothing is visible but does its job.

Comment: @Tomáš: The reason that the hidden inputs are not in the form is probably because the HTML code is incorrect. The `form`  and `input` tags should be either outside the `table` or inside a `td`. The browser tries to correct the code when it is parsed, and the `input` elements ends up outside the `form` elements.

Comment: Brilliant! Working perfectly in `td` Thank you once more.

Comment: @Tomáš: Is there some problem with the solution?